# how to remove brackets from NSarray

Tags: iphone, ios

i have an array where i am trying to remove the  brackets  from the nsarray

This is my output (
        (
        "2013-06-15 02:00"
    ),
        (
        "2013-06-16 02:00"
    ),
        (
        "2013-06-18 02:00"
    ),
        (
        "2013-06-19 02:00"
    ),
        (
        "2013-06-19 02:00"
    )
)

but i want to remove inner brackets and output as
(
    "2013-06-15 02:00",
    "2013-06-16 02:00",
    "2013-06-18 02:00",
    "2013-06-19 02:00",
    "2013-06-19 02:00"
)

Any one Please help me out to solve this issue

Comment: Iterate array objects and use **stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:** to replace ( and ).

Comment: Is this JSON response ?? Or just an Simple Array ?? If it is JSON response then every index of that Array has another Array and on that Array's 0 index you have that String ... If this is just an Array then you can replace ) and ( from every index of that Array by using `[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:<#(NSString *)#> withString:<#(NSString *)#>]` method ...

Comment: yes, this is a Json responce

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm answering to consider that this is an Simple `NSArray` -

Your array is like this -

```
 NSArray *array = @[@[@"2013-06-15 02:00"], @[@"2013-06-16 02:00"], @[@"2013-06-18 02:00"], @[@"2013-06-19 02:00"], @[@"2013-06-19 02:00"]];
 NSLog(@"\n%@",array);
```

And then output of this array is:-

(
        (
        "2013-06-15 02:00"
    ),
        (
        "2013-06-16 02:00"
    ),
        (
        "2013-06-18 02:00"
    ),
        (
        "2013-06-19 02:00"
    ),
        (
        "2013-06-19 02:00"
    )
)

Now lets filter this array -

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i=0; i<[array count]; i++)
{
    [newArray addObject:array[i][0]];
}

NSLog(@"\n%@", newArray);
```

Output is:-
(
    "2013-06-15 02:00",
    "2013-06-16 02:00",
    "2013-06-18 02:00",
    "2013-06-19 02:00",
    "2013-06-19 02:00"
)

Comment: what if i want data in ( "2013-06-15 02:00" ), ( "2013-06-16 02:00" ), ( "2013-06-18 02:00" ), ( "2013-06-19 02:00" ), ( "2013-06-19 02:00" )  this format

Comment: @shahrukhshikalgar and how is your current data ?

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771327/objective-c-addobject-to-store-array-return-extra-bracket-for-me-how-to-remove) i have posted que. here

Answer (score 1):

Use objectAtIndex as below:

```
[yourArray objectAtIndex:i]
```

where i represents index,if you want first string then use 0,second then 1,....etc.

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm in a canihazecode-mood:

```
NSArray *array = ...
NSMutableArray *cleanedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[array count]];
for (id object in array) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        if ([object count]) {
            [cleanedArray addObject:object[0]];
        }
        else {
            // empty array
        }
    }
    else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        NSRange openBracket = [object rangeOfString:@"("];
        NSString *temp = [object stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:openBracket withString:@""];
        NSRange closeBracket = [temp rangeOfString:@")" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
        temp = [temp stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:closeBracket withString:@""];
        [cleanedArray addObject:temp];
    }
    else {
        // unknown class
    }
}
```

you might want to figure out if your objects are strings or arrays, and remove the superfluous part.

Comment: Now I'm sure that this array cant be an array of string because if so then item should be in double quotes because it has special characters .... So probably it is an array of array.