# Objective C - addObject to store array return extra bracket for me how to remove

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

my data coming in this format

```
(
   (
      Male,
      Female
   ),
   (
      First,
      Second,
      Third
   )
)
```

and I want in this format

```
(
   Male,
   Female
),
(
   First,
   Second,
   Third
)
```

how to remove extra bracket from array

```
if ([[allObject objectForKey:@"Fid"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
        NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)[allObject objectForKey:@"Fid"];
        for (int i =0; i<arr.count; i++) {
            if ([[arr valueForKey:@"Values"]objectAtIndex:i] != (id)[NSNull null] ) {
                NSMutableArray *fetchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                [fetchArray addObjectsFromArray:[[arr valueForKey:@"Values"] objectAtIndex:i]];
                [fetchValue addObject:fetchArray];
            }
        }
}
```

I have tried `addObject` and `addObjectFromArray`
but in `addObjectFromArray` output comes in `(male,female,first,second,third)` and i want like `(male,female),(first,second,third)`

Comment: The first is an array of arrays and the second is 2 independent arrays you put together in a post.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i have some object which also contain null values so i am fetching data which `[arr valueForKey:@"Values"]` this key and storing one by one array in my fetchValue array. but it caries extra bracket

Comment: Why do you care what the text-representation of the array is?  Either the data is organized correctly, or it isn't.  If it's not, explain what you have and what you want.

Comment: (
   (
      Male,
      Female
   ),
   (
      First,
      Second,
      Third
   )
) this data returns count 1 but it contains actual 2 object and in future I want to fetch one by one array. so can you tell me how can i fetch value using for loop so i get (
   Male,
   Female
),
(
   First,
   Second,
   Third
) this

Comment: @shahrukhshikalgar If you will log an array of array then you will probably get the same response. Nothing is wrong here.

Comment: @shahrukhshikalgar What you get by this `NSLog(@"%@", array[0]);` ?

Comment: array[0] i get (male,female) and array[1] i got remaining array

Comment: @shahrukhshikalgar, the array is correct, you can get the object using the arrays index

Comment: yes.... I thought I was making something wrong. @TheTiger solved my query

Answer (score 0):

This line `[fetchValue addObject:fetchArray];` is the problem. You need use `=` and not `addObject`.

In your `fetchValue`mutableArray you are adding other mutableArray `fetchArray`, finally you get array of arrays. Only use `=`

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C doesn't care about you want. In this case, you can't get what you want.

You can have an array containing two arrays. That's what you got. You can't have nothing containing two arrays. It just doesn't make sense.

And note that your data isn't coming in this format. What you posted is the output of NSLog, it's not your data.